# ASP.NET Web API Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I would like to know if it is possible to do dependency injection (custom constructor) in a ASP.NET Web API without the use of third party libraries such as Unity or StructureMap and without Entity Framework.

What I would like to achieve is have a controller with a constructor such as:

```
public Controller(IDatabaseConnector connector) { ... }
```

I know for MVC you can make a custom ControllerFactory by inheriting from DefaultControllerFactory and then overriding the GetControllerInstance function. So I am sure there is an alternative for Web API.

Comment: Read up on `IDependencyResolver` for web api. Make sure it is for Web API as MVC has its own with the same name.

Comment: I ended up inheriting from IHttpControllerActivator and that did the trick for me.

Comment: When i was trying out asp core it had dependency injection in their sample page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703433.aspx

Comment: Dependency Injection doesn't require a DI Container at all. Hand-wiring your Dependency in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) is a common practice called [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). As you already noticed, you need to implement a custom `IHttpControllerActivator` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first you should define your own `IHttpControllerActivator`:

```
public class CustomControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        // Your logic to return an IHttpController
        // You can use a DI Container or you custom logic
    }
}
```

Then you should replace the default activator in the `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // ...

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
        typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
        new CustomControllerActivator());
}
```

Now you can use your rich `Controller` constructor:

```
public class UserController
{
    public UserController(
        IMapper mapper,
        ILogger logger,
        IUsersRepository usersRepository)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already did this as you could see in my comment on my post, but still thanks for the help! +1